# ¿Por qué no hace la conexión?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
proxy = open(file="proxylist.txt", mode="r")

def main():
    #exec(open("selectorproxy.py").read())
    try:
    
        proxy1 = proxy.readline()
        print(proxy1)
        consulta = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+proxy1+'/www.fotocasa.es/es/')

    except:
        main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Intento conectarme a través del proxy pero los errores son los siguientes:

> Invalid header value b'190.24.113.138:999\n'

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el valor leído desde el fichero incluye un carácter New Line (\n) que deberías quitar antes de usarlo en la consulta. Prueba algo como esto, cambia

```
proxy1 = proxy.readline()
```

por

```
proxy1 = proxy.readline().rstrip()
```

Comment: ¿Cómo podría ver el código de estado que me devuelve?

Comment: Prueba con code = consulta.getcode()

Comment: Yo haría `proxy1 = proxy.readline().rstrip("\n")` por que si no pasas ningún argumento al rstrip, también borrará los espacios a la derecha. Esto podría ser un comportamiento no deseado en algunos casos.

Comment: Pero no en este caso, ya que se va a concatenar para formar una url

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer `proxy1 = proxy.read().splitlines()`.
Con esto te devolvería una lista con todas las lineas que tengas en el `txt` sin los saltos de línea.

Comment: En lo posible hay que evitar el uso de read y readlines excepto que necesites cargar todo el archivo en memoria. En archivos grandes, cargar todas las lineas en memoria no es buena idea (y hasta podría no funcionar debido al exceso de memoria requerido).

Answer (score 0):

El error está en el `except`:

```
def main():
    try:
        # Un código que genera excepción.
    except:
        main()
```

En la función `main()` invocas a la función `main()` cuando ocurre una excepción. Eso es una llamada recursiva, y una vez que se produce el error, vuelves a ejecutar la misma función y a repetir el mismo error, una y otra vez.

Comment: Esto no es así porque hago un salto de línea cada vez que se repite la función ya que definí la apertura del stream antes de iniciar main()

Comment: es decir primero: 113.177.48.183:19132 después 179.1.73.100:999 y así sucesivamente... Ahora me gustaría imprimir el código de estado pero, no sé cómo puedo hacer esto, si sabes y puedes ayudarme, te lo agradecería.

Comment: Tu código tiene varios problemas más (te sobra un '\n', usas `exec`, ). Si no entiendes el problema que te señalo, dudo en tener una respuesta a tu alcance.

Comment: ¿Dónde está '\n'? exec lo pretendo utilizar más adelante.